# Load image from SD card using Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I've been trying and searching for an answer for the past 5 hours.
I'm storing image from google plus to local folder and using Glide library to load the image into imageview.

> the file uri is file:///storage/emulated/0/MyApp/ProfilePics/profile_user1.jpg

I'm using below code for image loading through glide:

```
Glide.with(ProfileActivity.this).load(Uri.fromFile(new File(sharedPrefMan.getImageUrl()))).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_profile).into(imgProfilePic);
```

where sharedPrefMan.getImageUrl() returns /storage/emulated/0/MyApp/ProfilePics/profile_user1.jpg

The image is present in the given location.

Comment: you didn't specified what the issue you are having with this code ..??

Answer (score 40):

If you have original path of image than you have to converted to URI and showing image like this

```
    String fileName = "1.jpg";
    String completePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + fileName;

    File file = new File(completePath);
    Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    Glide.with(this)
            .load(imageUri)
                    .into(imgView);
```

Seems like you have **URI** than you have to put than **URI** only

```
   Glide.with(this)
            .load(Uri)
                    .into(imgView);
```

Answer (score 11):

I am using this version

> implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'

You have to pass image uri like this given below:

```
 Glide.with(this)
                .load(Uri.fromFile(new File(imageStoragePath)))
                .apply(new RequestOptions().override(100, 100))
                .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just use below line:-**

```
Glide.with(context).load(uri).transform(new Transform()).into(view)
```

And for getting uri use below code:-

```
 Uri.fromFile(new File(Yourpath));
```

Answer (score 0):

**This Worked for me as long as you Add permissions.**

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"xxx/xxx/"+imgName.jpg);
                        Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                        Glide.with(this).load(imageUri).into(tvBestSellingProductImage3);
```