# How to resize images at runtime for different screens?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, nine-patch, resize-image

I know that in Android Studio there are some plugins for including a drawable that help in creating a ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, etc image resource.

But suppose I have an app in which some users upload images to a server and then I download the images and display them for other users, how can I adapt them so that they adapt to ldpi, mdpi, hdpi screens? Is there a library that runs on the server or client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are two ways , either you do it or let other do it

1. you can use `picasso`(image loading library ) with fit function and just relax .[link](https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit)
2. find the required size and compress the image size with required parameter.[android guide](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

there are couple of other library like picasso,glide,universal image loader and lot other though picasso and glide are most popular among android developers

Code Reference Links :

[**Picasso**](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

[Picasso library to download images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330772/why-use-android-picasso-library-to-download-images)

[Resize image to full width and fixed height with Picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823249/resize-image-to-full-width-and-fixed-height-with-picasso)

[**Glide**](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

[Load image from SD card using Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443171/load-image-from-sd-card-using-glide)

Pros of libs :

- In-Build image downloading mechanism with other features like animation,re-sizing etc
- In-Build cache mechanism
- Optimized written code by experienced coders
- Can load images to bitmap , from resources etc
- Animation support

Cons :

- Stay in touch with docs for new updates and more consistent features