# GridView: The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.Skipped x frames error when using various images

Tags: java, android, exception, gridview

Hey in this program I have set a GridView according to the text it has but when running the app the app lags alot on the emulator as well as on the device. And the error

> "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." is given 
>   I guess thats what causing the problem here.

Here is my ImageAdapter file

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;

}

private Context context;
String mobile;
private final String[] mobileValues;

int[] imagesArr = new int[]{R.drawable.badminton, R.drawable.cricket, R.drawable.basketball, R.drawable.carrom,
        R.drawable.handball, R.drawable.humanfoosball, R.drawable.kabaddi, R.drawable.khokho, R.drawable.chess,
        R.drawable.longjump, R.drawable.streetsoccer, R.drawable.shotput, R.drawable.volleyball, R.drawable.tugofwar,
        R.drawable.tabletennis, R.drawable.handball, R.drawable.rellayrace};

public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] mobileValues) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mobileValues = mobileValues;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    View row = convertView;

    if (row == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //row = new View(context);

        // get layout from grid_itemxml.xml
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);

        // set value into textview
        holder.textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);

        holder.textView.setText(mobileValues[position]);

        // set image based on selected text
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
        mobile = mobileValues[position];


        if (mobile.equals("Badminton")) {
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(imagesArr[0]);

        }
        if (mobile.equals("Cricket")) {
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(imagesArr[1]);
        }
        if (mobile.equals("Basketball")) {
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(imagesArr[2]);
        }
        if (mobile.equals("Carrom")) {
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(imagesArr[3]);
        }
        if (mobile.equals("Handball")) {
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(imagesArr[4]);
        }
        if (mobile.equals("Human Foosball")) {
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(imagesArr[5]);
        }
        if (mobile.equals("Kabaddi")) {
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(imagesArr[6]);
        }
        if (mobile.equals("Khokho")) {
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(imagesArr[7]);
        }
        if (mobile.equals("Chess")) {
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(imagesArr[8]);
        }
        if (mobile.equals("Longjump")) {
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(imagesArr[9]);
        }
        if (mobile.equals("Streetsoccer")) {
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(imagesArr[10]);
        }
        if (mobile.equals("Shotput")) {
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(imagesArr[11]);
        }
        if (mobile.equals("Volleyball")) {
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(imagesArr[12]);
        }
        if (mobile.equals("Tugofwar")) {
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(imagesArr[13]);
        }
        if (mobile.equals("Table Tennis")) {
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(imagesArr[14]);
        }
        if (mobile.equals("Relayrace")) {
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(imagesArr[15]);
        }

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    return row;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mobileValues.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The images inside your project are taking too much time to load the images, though the android memory resources are limited to app.There are couple of solution that you can try

- Keep image size low (downside will be bad  quality on bigger screens).
- Compress image to required screen resolution size at run time.

The easy way is use image loading libraries.  Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38782076/how-to-resize-images-at-runtime-for-different-screens) for details 
e.g

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.drawableName).fit().centerCrop().into(imageViewFit)
```