# Android Studio 2.1.2 http GET error

Tags: android, http, get

I have been fighting with this for 2 days now, end of the line for me. It seems I am having trouble in getting my makeHttpRequest. I can add data, view all records in a table but I just can't seem to get a single record data to my page, app crashes completely "Unfortunately 'app_name" has stopped.

Below is my JSonParser file and the Activity file. Any suggestions will be welcome. I have read through tons of similar questions but none seemed to have worked...

Thanks all.

Errors in JsonParser as per image 'JSonParser, no errors in my Activity file as per image 'Activity'[JSonParser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kfXO.png)

[image: Activity]

Log error as follow ---

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: ...MyApp.co.za.androidtophp, PID: 32447
>                                                                                    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                                        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
>                                                                                        at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
>                                                                                        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
>                                                                                        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
>                                                                                        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:185)
>                                                                                        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:172)
>                                                                                        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:130)
>                                                                                        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.executeOriginal(DefaultRequestDirector.java:1337)
>                                                                                        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:705)
>                                                                                        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:578)
>                                                                                        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:494)
>                                                                                        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:472)
>                                                                                        at ...MyApp.co.za.androidtophp.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:63)
>                                                                                        at ...MyApp.co.za.androidtophp.EditProductActivity$GetProductDetails$1.run(EditProductActivity.java:134)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Gradle files is all in there as far as apache is concerned -

1. useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
2. compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
   compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
   compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'

Comment: Please post code in a text block. Do away with the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because you are trying to make the HTTP Request synchronous. Please create an AsyncTask or disable strict mode (only clever when there's no problem when the app could hange some seconds).

**Warning: Don't use this for public app releases!!!**

For disabling Strict Mode, add following code in your `onCreate()` (right after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`)

```
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Please dont advertise to use StrictMode. Bad practise.

Comment: There's a note it's better to use an AsyncTask @greenapps 
and a disclaimer that disabling StrictMode will result in problems (app could hange some seconds)..

Comment: Dario, I owe you HUGE BIG TIME, works a charm, thank you. Is this however safe practice? What would the work around be - using AsyncTask?

Comment: Thank you, but PLEASE, don't start using this for public app releases! It's just a workaround, and if it cause bugs to you, create an `AsyncTask`

Comment: Please refer to the doc for seeing how to create an AsyncTask.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Not to worry, played around with AsyncTask and it is working for now ... in a sense. Seems a lot saver than the first part. Took some info from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289623/how-to-use-asynctask/18289746#18289746

Answer (score 2):

Never execute longer running task on main thread specially during network calls where you have no idea when the response will come due to various factors like signal strength , server crash/busy etc.

Put your all network call either in  `Asynchtasks` if they are relatively small like download image around 1-3 MB, doc/files etc or for longer tasks use `HTTPUrlConncetion calls` or you can use some networking libraries for better memory usage and optimizations , efficient cache mechanism.

#### Volley

- Easy to use
- Matured and backed by google

#### Retrofit

- Has inbuild integration/support with useful libraries like

  - **GSON** - for parsing `JSONObject/JSONArrays`
  - **Okio** to support java.io and java.nio to make it much easier to access, store and process your data using `ByteString` and `Buffer`
  - **RxJava** - Observable patterns

though the above libraries like `GSON` etc can be used with Volley too as a separate dependancy.

There are many other open source libraries like `Ion` , `OKHttp` etc too, though the above are more popular but if you want your own customization then you can simply use `HTTPUrlConncetion`.

Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception) for networking call examples using threads and for more info about network libraries try [comparison between OkHTTP, Retrofit, Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-volley) .

There  also some better options for Image downloading network calls i.e you can use **Picasso , Glide , Fresco , Universal Image loader** etc. try [this link for image downloading libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38782076/how-to-resize-images-at-runtime-for-different-screens/38782180#38782180)

Comment: Agreed, the more I read up around this, the more clear it becomes to allow for signals, server etc. a Bit of a newbie to Android as my experience lies with desktop/web. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: My pleasure Mr.Andre Oosthuizen.