# Loading image in android imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-glide

How to load images in same image view from web or local android gallery?

I have an image view which has three options for loading images templates from web service,from gallery, from camera.I am using Glide library to load images from web service, Now, if i load image from web by glide and remove that image by remove button which i have for removing a picture after i pick image from gallery it doesn't load the image from gallery instead load the same image from glide which i removed before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load image from SD card using Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443171/load-image-from-sd-card-using-glide)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write the code like this for loading image .

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(imgUrl)
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imageView);
```

[Glide Library Intoduction](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en) Go through with this link, hope it will be work

Answer (score 0):

You can use Picasso library. Image loading using Picasso is very easy, you can do it like this way

> Picasso.with(context).load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEIKP.jpg").into(imageView);

and in their [website](http://square.github.io/picasso/) you can get every details.

and another Library is Glide. You can use Glide too for loading image..

You can also use Glide:

> Glide.with(context).load(image).asBitmap().placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).error(R.drawable.error).into(imageview);

Comment: Picasso has many issues with image sizes and http so i found that glide is better choice.